# How to convert blob from MYSQL to base64

Tags: node.js, base64, blob

I am using Node.js and MYSQL to get a blob and this is how I retrieve blob data from my database

```
app.get('/Northwest-Panay-Peninsula-Natural-Park',(request,response)=>{
db.query('select Image from nppnp_species_pictures LIMIT 3', function(err, result) {
    
    //if I do this it lonly gives me a value AAAAA
    var base64data = Buffer.from(result, 'binary').toString('base64');
    response.send(base64data);
});    
});
```

the result from the query gives me

```
[{"Image":{"type":"Buffer","data":[137,80,78,71,13,10,26,10,0,0,0,13,73,72
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to decode only the relevant part of the result.

```
var base64data = Buffer.from(result[0].Image.data).toString('base64');
```

Comment: I got an error `The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, ArrayBuffer, or Array or an Array-like Object. Received undefined`

Comment: I edited the answer. Try it now. Let me know what the `console('result[0].Image.data')` outputs if that fails.

Comment: Still got the error `var base64data = Buffer.from(result[0].Image.data).toString('base64');`

Comment: You need to provide the requested info

Comment: Im sorry but I cant understand what youtr saying

Comment: What does this say `console('result[0].Image.data')`

Comment: Console i snot a function but when you say `console.log('result[0].Image.data');` it gives me `result[0].Image.data`

Comment: Post a sample of that data

Comment: Good example to read blob it works for me perfectly. has just to make some changing so you need to remove the `data`, the code should be like `var base64data = Buffer.from(result[0].Image).toString('base64');` hope this will help